# Haar measure and push forward in the subset of squares

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure, pushforward

Let $K$ be a compact group with Haar probability measure $m$, let $K^2 = \{k^2 : k\in K\}$ and suppose that $m(K^2)>0$. Show that if $m(A\cap K^2) = m(K^2)$ then $m(\{k\in K : k^2\in A\})=1$.

Comment: I think the $O(2)$ example works here too (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4842086). Take $A=SO(2)\setminus\{1\}.$ Then $k^2\in A$ if and only if $k\in SO(2)\setminus\{\pm 1\}.$